# Grails duplicating json on query

Tags: json, grails

I'm learning grails with json and I encountered this problem, which my JSON duplicate 4x in the same object and should be each, not all together:

```
[{"id":[2,1,4,3],"address":"[test.web.Address : 2, test.web.Address : 1, test.web.Address : 4, test.web.Address : 3]","range":[300,200,500,400],"placetype":"[Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous]"},{"id":[2,1,4,3],"address":"[test.web.Address : 2, test.web.Address : 1, test.web.Address : 4, test.web.Address : 3]","range":[300,200,500,400],"placetype":"[Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous]"},{"id":[2,1,4,3],"address":"[test.web.Address : 2, test.web.Address : 1, test.web.Address : 4, test.web.Address : 3]","range":[300,200,500,400],"placetype":"[Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous]"},{"id":[2,1,4,3],"address":"[test.web.Address : 2, test.web.Address : 1, test.web.Address : 4, test.web.Address : 3]","range":[300,200,500,400],"placetype":"[Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous, Dangerous]"}]
```

My domain Address:

```
Long id
String street
String city
Long zip;
int number
```

My domain Place:

```
Long id
Long range
PlaceType type
Address address
```

My Controller:

```
def avoid() {
    def result = [];
    def r = []
    def a = Place.executeQuery("select distinct a from Place a where a.type = 1")

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        println(result)
        result.add(a)
    }

    if (result) {
            result.each() { place ->
                r << [id: place.id,
                        address: place.address.street.toString(),
                        range: place.range,
                        placetype: place.type.toString()
                ];
            }
        } else {
            println('error')
        }
        return jsonRender("JSON", params.callback, r)
}
```

PlaceType enum

```
enum PlaceType {

DANGEROUS('Dangerous', 1),
NOT_DANGEROUS('Not Dangerous', 2)

private final int id;
private final String description;

public PlaceType(String description, int id) {
    this.description = description
    this.id = id
}

public static PlaceType getById(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return DANGEROUS
        case 2:
            return NOT_DANGEROUS
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    description
}

public short getId() {
    id
}
```

}

Where I'm doing wrong? edit: test.web.Address now show the real address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of "noise" in your groovy code...
I'd put it like that:

```
def avoid(){
  render Place.findAllByType( PlaceType.Dangerous ).collect{ Place place ->
    [id: place.id,
     address: place.address.street.toString(),
     range: place.range,
     placetype: place.type.toString()
    ]
  } as JSON
}
```

In this case you have a couple of possible error sources fewer.

Also I think, that stuff like `place.type.toString()` is wrong. The object shall be JSON-ified directly and the output should be a JSON-object rather that default `toString()` implementation

Comment: In case of enum PlaceType, it wont work. Ive updated my question.

Comment: If you can, please update your answer with enumtype so I can accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Hm the `PlaceType.Dangerous` it won't do, but with `PlaceType.getById(1)`, will do.! Thanks!

Comment: `PlaceType.DANGEROUS` should be uppercase, of course. Try it! btw, why do you need numeric constants here? it can perfectly live w/o them.

Comment: O yeah, it worked, I got it from an example, so still I need more learning.

Comment: I suggest you to pay more attention to learning `groovy` first. Thus you can squeeze way more fun out of grails :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the method

```
jsonRender ("JSON", params.callback, r)
```

Please try this:

```
render r as JSON
```

and don't forget the import:

```
import grails.converters.*
```

see doc for render method: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

or try to use the new response method: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html

Comment: Yes! But my `formatAndRender` method has xml or json.